# How to test ionic application in production environment

Tags: angular, ionic2, protractor

I want to test my ionic application e2e in the production environment using protractor.
The main challenge and that I am facing is that

How to start seeting the protractor environment in production? 
Is is same as we set up in development?

Secondly, If I ran my test suite in production will it build the application each time when I ran the test cases?